# Laravel 5 | Test with POST

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, laravel-5, assertions

I Use PHPUnit testing with laravel5,

I get proper status code when i use "GET" method,

```
 $this->call('GET','admin'); 

 $this->assertResponseOk();        //Status Code: 200
```

If I try to get status code of the page by "POST" method,

```
       $param = [
        'id' => 2
        ];
    $this->call('POST', 'shopping/remove', array(), array(), array(),array(), $param);

    $this->assertResponseOk();      //Status Code: 500
```

Whats wrong with my code ....?

I wanna to do POST level submission test ...

Comment: You can see what the response says by checking $this->response in your test.

Comment: have you checked your routes.php file ? does it have rule like Route::post('shopping/remove' or Route::any('shopping/remove'

Comment: You are putting the `$param` on the `content`  argument place. You can do it just like the `get`, `$this->call('POST', 'shopping/remove', $param)`. However, do not forget to include the _csrf token_  if it is needed (add `'_token' => csrf_token(),` to your param array for example)

Comment: I Do that also ji....